# Scalar product normalized vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I read that this equivalence holds:

$$\langle x,y \rangle + a \Leftrightarrow \langle x,y+ax \rangle$$

if $x$ has norm $1$, with $\langle\cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ being the dot product.

However I don't see how, since in the case of the right-hand term we end up with $xax$, which I am not sure how to simplify..

Any help (hints as well) appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\langle x, y+ax\rangle = \langle x, y \rangle + \langle x, ax\rangle$$

Also, if this is a vector space over $\mathbb R$, then you have, for any pair of vectors $x_1,x_2$ and any scalar $\alpha$, the equality $$\langle x_1, \alpha x_2\rangle = \alpha\langle x_1, x_2\rangle$$

Comment: Aha...starting to remember, the dot product is bilinear...but then when we end up with <x,y> + a <x,x>, this to be equivalent to <x,y> + a, <x,x> would have to be equal to 1 - is it..? Why?

Comment: @Pegah The norm of $x$ is.... ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By linearity of the do product we have:

$$
\langle x,y+ax\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle+a\langle x,x\rangle
$$